# python regular expression for Extracting URL in between matched quotes whether it may be single,double or (

Tags: python, regex

I am using python regular expressions for retrieving all links from webpage.
My intention is to retrieve links from different attributes like  src,href,contnet and image background links as well. Below is the code i used .

```
import re
import urllib2
page=urllib2.urlopen('http://xxxx.html').read();
page2=re.sub(r'(?s)<!--.*?-->', '', page); #this is for restricting links from commented code.
links=re.findall(r'\s*[\"\'\(](http|\/)(.*?)[\"\'\)]',page2)
```

Able to retrieve all links from webpage by using above code,but the problem is sometimes it is not retrieving the complete url for ex

```
<a href="http://xxx.yyy.com/help/xxx(yyy)_Help.exe"
```

expected output should be 'http://xxx.yyy.com/help/xxx(yyy)_Help.exe' ,but actual output is 'http://xxx.yyy.com/help/xxx'.

is there any way to restrict ,if the string starts with single or double or ( ,it has to retrieve the link up to matching quote has found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya, this should be possible.But it only works for quotes..

```
>>> s = '<a href="http://xxx.yyy.com/help/xxx(yyy)_Help.exe" '
>>> re.findall(r'\s*(["\'])((?:http|\/).*?)\1[>\s]', s)
[('"', 'http://xxx.yyy.com/help/xxx(yyy)_Help.exe')]
>>> [i[1] for i in re.findall(r'\s*(["\'])((?:http|\/).*?)\1[>\s]', s)]
['http://xxx.yyy.com/help/xxx(yyy)_Help.exe']
>>>
```

**Doubt? Play [Here..](https://regex101.com/r/fQ8aY2/1)**

If you the regex also to work for brackets then use,

```
\s*(["\'(])((?:http|\/).*?)\1[>\s]|\(((?:http|\/).*?)\)[>\s]
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fQ8aY2/2)

Comment: not able to retrieve links from this pattern by using the second regualr expression.image:url(http://xxx.yyy.com/www/2014/xxx_zzz/4zzz-nnn-desc.png) and able to retrieve link from this pattern url(/xxx/yyy/zzz.png). Can you please explain a bit?

Comment: @suneetha because `(xxx.yyy.com/www/2014/xxx_zzz/4zzz-nnn-desc.png)` doesn't starts with `/`. This `(?:http|\/)` regex assumes that there must be `http` or `/` exists next to `(` or `'` or `"`

Answer (score 0):

The following regex will match single or double or () quote pairs:

```
import re
page2 = """
<a href="https://xxx.yyy.com/help/xxx(yyy)_Help.exe">
<a href=(http://xxx.yyy.com/help/xxx(yyy)_Help.exe)>
<a href='http://xxx.yyy.com/help/xxx(yyy)_Help'.exe'>
<a href="http://xxx.yyy.com/help/xxx(yyy)_Help.exe'>
<a href='http://xxx.yyy.com/help/xxx(yyy)_Help.exe)>
... """

pattern = '(?P<q>"|\')(https?:\/\/.*)(?P=q)|\((https?:\/\/.*)\)'
links = [ m[1] if m[1] else m[2] for m in re.findall(pattern, page2)]
print links
```

Output:

```
['https://xxx.yyy.com/help/xxx(yyy)_Help.exe',
 'http://xxx.yyy.com/help/xxx(yyy)_Help.exe',
 "http://xxx.yyy.com/help/xxx(yyy)_Help'.exe"]
```